# log4j log file is not getting generated while running jar file from the command line

Tags: selenium, log4j

I am working on selenium automation. And, I have created a maven project in Eclipse.

Log4j2.properties file is placed in src/test/resources folder.

The src/test/java folder contains the scripts for various feature of the web application under test.

The log4j.java file under src/test/java folder is as below:

```
public class Log4jTest {
    
    public static Logger logg = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);      
    public void info(String m) {        
        System.out.println("Test Message: " + m);
        logg.info(m);
    }
}
```

I have used the below statement in the scripts where I require to record log messages.

Example:

```
 public static Logger logg = LogManager.getLogger(UserCreation.class);  


public static Logger logg = LogManager.getLogger(UserRegistration.class);
```

When I execute this project from the main method, I am able to see the log4j log file getting generated and also logs printed in Eclipse console.
But, when I generated a jar file of this project and run from command line then the log4j log file is not generated and also unable to see any logs printed in the command line.

Could anyone please help on this?